# Principal component analysis before nearest neighbor search

Tags: pca, matrix, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a large data table (~500,000 rows) of normalized metrics (by Z-score) that looks like this:

```
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| ID   | M1            | M2            | M3            | M4            |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|    1 | -0.3993408978 |  1.1276756525 | -0.0048326259 | -1.3967152834 |
|    2 | -0.3244025409 |  1.3201564550 | -0.0548842102 | -1.3317097425 |
|    3 | -0.3025048971 |  1.0483477116 | -0.0849148855 | -1.3642125130 |
|    4 | -0.2436245084 |  1.2600721121 |  0.0101827132 | -1.2992069721 |
|    5 | -0.2781734169 |  0.3511493504 | -0.3752114475 | -1.4617208242 |
|    6 | -0.2815801203 |  0.3369039595 | -0.3201552033 | -1.4617208242 |
|    7 | -0.2197803259 |  0.5600918531 | -0.1750069261 | -1.3967152834 |
|    8 | -0.1579796672 |  0.3966214657 | -0.0949251130 | -1.3967152834 |
|    9 | -0.1209969074 |  0.0815875754 | -0.0799097717 | -1.4292180538 |
|   10 | -0.1910693198 | -0.6976287961 | -0.2500836253 | -1.5917314291 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+...500,000 rows
```

I also have a query point that looks like this:

```
+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| M1            | M2           | M3            | M4            |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| -0.5185617805 | 0.0669142157 | -0.2050375938 | -1.6918823719 |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+ (1 row)
```

I then use the query point to create a list of 300 neighbors nearest to it (with a multidimensional k-NN algorithm).

**What I would like to do is to is to transform the data with PCA before doing the k-NN search.**

I can do this with the [ALGLIB library](http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/principalcomponentsanalysis.php)

```
INPUT PARAMETERS:
    X           -   dataset, array[0..NPoints-1,0..NVars-1].
                    matrix contains ONLY INDEPENDENT VARIABLES.
    NPoints     -   dataset size, NPoints>=0
    NVars       -   number of independent variables, NVars>=1

OUTPUT:
    Info        -   return code:
                    * -4, if SVD subroutine haven't converged
                    * -1, if wrong parameters has been passed (NPoints<0,
                          NVars<1)
                    *  1, if task is solved
    S2          -   array[0..NVars-1]. variance values corresponding
                    to basis vectors.
    V           -   array[0..NVars-1,0..NVars-1]
                    matrix, whose columns store basis vectors.
```

So as far as I understand, S2 will contain my transformed data - 
**but how do I transform the query point in the same manner - so I could use it for the K-NN search on the transformed data?**

I am guessing I need to use `V` - the column that stores basis vectors. And then I'm guessing its some sort of matrix operation to transform my query point about the appropriate basis vector?

Am I correct in my assumptions?
How do I do this?

This is all very new to me and I have no relevant background, so if possible please provide a lay man explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question makes one to wonder *why* you need to do PCA first. Are you going to reduce the dimensionality or just rotate the axes of space?

Anyway. PCA is just a particular case of orthogonal rotation of axes (your variables) in space: **newdata = olddata*Q** where **Q** is the rotation matrix, called matrix of eigenvectors in PCA, you obtain this matrix via eigen-decomposition or singular-value-decomposition in any software that has matrix capabilities. You just use the above formula with both your 500000-row data and your 1-row "query point" data (you may actually concatenate into 500001 rows table). In this way you obtain new coordinates for all the 500001 points and you may proceed with whatever you like to do next.

Comment: I was under the impression that PCA can eliminate latent correlations as well as allow you to drop the dimensions that contribute least to the overall variance.